# Swift - How to save entries to core data in a loop

Tags: swift, core-data

I have 2 entities: Series and Season. A Series can have multiple seasons, so I set the relationship type to "to many". season_counter is an Int Array, containing the amount of episodes.

```
let newSeries = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Series", inManagedObjectContext: self.context!) as! Series

for var i = 0; i < season_counter.count; ++i{
         let newSeason = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Season", inManagedObjectContext: self.context!) as! Season
         newSeason.value = i+1
         newSeason.episodes = season_counter[i]
         newSeries.setValue(NSSet(object: newSeason), forKey: "seasons")

     do {
         try context?.save()
    } catch _ {
    }
}
```

While debugging I noticed, that season_counter stores the correct values. When I display the results, I have only the last season stored (for example 13 episodes, seasons.count is 1):

```
do {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Season")
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "series = %@", series)
    try seasons = context?.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [Season]

    print(seasons.count)
    print(seasons[0].episodes)
} catch {
}
```

Any tips to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In each pass through your loop, you're throwing away the previous value of `seasons` and replacing it with a set that contains only one `season` (the newly created `newSeason`):

```
     newSeries.setValue(NSSet(object: newSeason), forKey: "seasons")
```

Instead of doing that, build up a set of all of the `newSeason` instances, and then call `setValue:forKey:` once, with that set.

Your life will be easier, by the way, if you create subclasses of `NSManagedObject` and get out of the "value for key" business.

Comment: I got your point. I have subclasses like this one: 

    import Foundation
    import CoreData

    class Season: NSManagedObject {
    }

The NSManaged Values are here: (with @)

    import Foundation
    import CoreData

    extension Season {

    NSManaged var id: NSNumber?
    NSManaged var value: NSNumber?
    NSManaged var episodes: NSNumber?
    NSManaged var series: Series?

    }

How do I go on now?

Answer (score 0):

```
newSeries.setValue(NSSet(object: newSeason), forKey: "seasons")
```

With this line you always create a new set of seasons containing exaclty one `Season` object - `newSeason`.

Try to do that:

```
var prevSeasons = newSeries.valueForKey("seasons")  
prevSeasons.insert(newSeason)
newSeries.setValue(prevSeasons, forKey: "seasons")
```